# JsonPath expression with filters in Spring MVC test

Tags: java, json, spring, jsonpath, spring-test-mvc

I have a controller that returns a list of sections. Each of these sections have a type. I want to test that the section of type "JOB" have a field "functions" with a size of 3.

Here is my code:

```
mockMvc.perform(get(url)
        .contentType(MediaTypes.HAL_JSON)
        .accept(MediaTypes.HAL_JSON))
        .andDo(print())
        .andExpect(status().isOk())
        .andExpect(jsonPath("$._embedded.content", 
                hasSize(equalTo(2))))
        .andExpect(jsonPath("$._embedded.content[?(@.type=='JOB')].functions", 
                hasSize(equalTo(3))));
```

The JSON returned by the controller (simplified for legibility):

```
{
   "_embedded":{
      "content":[
         {
            "subsections":null,
            "type":"PROFILE",
            "createdDate":null,
            "lastModifiedDate":null
         },
         {
            "functions":[
               {
                  "rank":845131,
                  "function":"9IXZT"
               },
               {
                  "rank":82701,
                  "function":"T91WX"
               },
               {
                  "rank":98686,
                  "function":"PA7NA"
               }
            ],
            "type":"JOB",
            "createdDate":null,
            "lastModifiedDate":null
         }
      ]
   }
}
```

I tested the expression with [this tool](http://jsonpath.com/) against that JSON and works correctly, but when running the test I'm getting this assertion error:

```
java.lang.AssertionError: JSON path "$._embedded.content[?(@.type=='JOB')].functions"
Expected: a collection with size <3>
    but: collection size was <1>
        at org.hamcrest.MatcherAssert.assertThat(MatcherAssert.java:20)
        at org.springframework.test.util.JsonPathExpectationsHelper.assertValue(JsonPathExpectationsHelper.java:74)
        at org.springframework.test.web.servlet.result.JsonPathResultMatchers$1.match(JsonPathResultMatchers.java:86)
        at org.springframework.test.web.servlet.MockMvc$1.andExpect(MockMvc.java:171)
        ...
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Adding .* to the end of the expression solved the problem, so now it looks like this:

```
$._embedded.content[?(@.type=='JOB')].functions.*
```

I don't understand why the first expression in the example is working but I have to add .* to the second one. If someone knows, please explain.

Answer (score 3):

There is a difference when adding the `.*`. When I fill in your data at [JSONPath Expression Tester](https://jsonpath.curiousconcept.com/)
I get a slight but important difference:

### Case 1

`$._embedded.content[?(@.type=='JOB')].functions` yields

```
[
   [
      {
         "rank":845131,
         "function":"9IXZT"
      },
      {
         "rank":82701,
         "function":"T91WX"
      },
      {
         "rank":98686,
         "function":"PA7NA"
      }
   ]
]
```

### Case 2

and `$._embedded.content[?(@.type=='JOB')].functions.*` yields

```
[
   {
      "rank":845131,
      "function":"9IXZT"
   },
   {
      "rank":82701,
      "function":"T91WX"
   },
   {
      "rank":98686,
      "function":"PA7NA"
   }
]
```

So for case 1 when you take the root node (which is an array) you have *one element* as direct child: the array containing three objects. Therefore the assertion found an array (collection) whith size one.
For case 2 you have the array root node *containing three objects* leading to a count of three for the collection.

Maybe this is not true for other implementations. In this example I used the *JSONPath 0.3.4* Implementation under *Flow Communications*.

---

The `.` after `functions` sets the root level of the result to this element and `*` means *take all elements* under this root.

I am not confident enough to explain the exact behaviour behind `$._embedded.content[?(@.type=='JOB')].functions`. But I think it has something to do with the filter `?(@.type=='JOB')`

https://github.com/json-path/JsonPath#what-is-returned-when

Comment: Great explanation! Thank you!